# Sum of elements (4) on mulitple lines in 2d array (txt file)

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file that reads:

Left Behind,Lahaye,F,7,11.25

A Tale of Two Cities,Dickens,F,100,8.24

Hang a Thousand Trees with Ribbons,Rinaldi,F,30,16.79

Saffy's Angel,McKay,F,20,8.22

Each Little Bird that Sings,Wiles,F,10,7.70

Abiding in Christ,Murray,N,3,12.20

Bible Prophecy,Lahaye and Hindson,N,5,14.95

Captivating,Eldredge,N,12,16

Growing Deep in the Christian Life,Swindoll,N,11,19.95

Prayers that Heal the Heart,Virkler,N,4,12.00

Grow in Grace,Ferguson,N,3,11.95

The Good and Beautiful God,Smith,N,7,11.75

Victory Over the Darkness,Anderson,N,12,16

The last element of each line is a price.  I would like to add up all the prices.  I've been searching for so many hours now and cannot find a thing to answer my question.  This seems soooo easy but I cannot figure it out!!!  Please help out.  BTW, this list is bound to change (adding of lines, deletion of lines, altering of lines) so if you can, please nothing concrete but instead leave the code open to changes.  Thanks!!!

Just so you can see my pooooorrrr work, here is what I have (I think I deleted my code and rewrote a different way for several hours now.):

```
    Dim Inv() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt")

    Dim t As Integer = Inv.Count - 1
    Dim a As Integer = 0 to t
    Dim sumtotal As String = sumtotal + Inv(4)
```

also,
for each line has either an "F" or an "N". how do I add up all the F's and all the N's. Do I do it via if statements?

Comment: I'd try starting with a string split to get an array and then just use the last element which will be the price: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Comment: can you elaborate more?  I mean via code?  I am definitely a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll be better off using Double as your type instead of String.  Second, observe how I use the Split function on each line, cast its last element as a double, and add it to the total.  Yes, using an If Statement is how you can determine whether or not to add to the count of F or the count of N.

```
    Dim lstAllLines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt").ToList()

    Dim dblTotal As Double = 0.0
    Dim intCountOfF As Integer = 0
    Dim intCountOfN As Integer = 0

    For Each strLine As String In lstAllLines

        Dim lstCells As List(Of String) = strLine.Split(",").ToList()

        dblTotal += CDbl(lstCells(3))

        If lstCells(2) = "F" Then

            intCountOfF += 1

        Else

            intCountOfN += 1

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Awesome! this one seems promising.  Now, how do I get this to display in a msgbox?  Which one is the TOTAL PRICE variable?

Comment: C'mon, Noob!  dblTotal is the Total.  To display in a message box, simply do: Msgbox(dblTotal.ToString())

Comment: what kind of education you got?

Comment: the third element, or (2), for each line has either an "F" or an "N".  how do I add up all the F's and all the N's.  Do I do it via if statements?  If you could show me an example, that would be great!

Comment: I edited the question and answer to include the example you need.  If you found it helpful, please make sure to accept this as the answer to your question.

Comment: how do I make this my answer?

Comment: Hover over the checkmark next to my answer and then press the left mouse button.